# How to reshape this kind of data and train it by using SVM?

Tags: python, svm

Sample data here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ngjFNALjzMqLknPsq5cgG4JbchwzVrjo/view?usp=sharing

My data have 1024x1776 column.
This is my code

```
    # Importing the libraries
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd
    
    # Importing the dataset
    dataset = pd.read_csv('14ns.csv')
    X = np.array(dataset).ravel()
    y = np.array(dataset).ravel()
    
    # Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)
    
    #Preprocessing
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    sc = StandardScaler()
    X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
    
    # Fitting Kernel SVM to the Training set
    from sklearn.svm import SVC
    classifier = SVC(kernel='poly', degree=8)
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
    
    # Predicting the Test set results
    y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
    
    # Applying k-Fold Cross Validation
    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
    accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = classifier, X = X_train, y = y_train, cv = 10)
    accuracies.mean()
    accuracies.std()
    
    from sklearn import metrics
    # Model Accuracy: how often is the classifier correct?
    print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
    print("Precision:",metrics.precision_score(y_test, y_pred))
    print("Recall:",metrics.recall_score(y_test, y_pred))
    print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

Then I found some errors here

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[  76.251429   19.851129   29.030629 ...   43.291237   71.803156
1914.573143].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Can help me to reshape my data and apply it by using SVM? I have no idea, I'm a beginner.

Comment: I think there is a solution in the error message.

Comment: Which line caused this error (can you provide the line number in the error traceback)? Have you tried reshaping the array as suggested in the error traceback?

Comment: What is the shape of `dataset` ?

Comment: @user2246849 1023 rows x 1776 columns

Comment: @AravindG. The error in the module is at line 18.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 18, in <module>
    X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)

Comment: @AravindG. I have tried reshaping as suggested, but still getting the error, I think I corrected it incorrectly as suggested by the error traceback, can you help me? thanks

Comment: @MechanicPig But I don't know how to use the solution, I'm still getting the error, please help me.

Comment: @AravindG. I get this error 'ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'' when I add X = X.reshape(-1,1) after X = np.array(dataset).ravel()
y = np.array(dataset).ravel()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 25, in <module>
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

Comment: @KohKhengHong would it be ok if you include a sample of your data in here?

Comment: Are your labels in a column of `dataset` ? Because at the moment `X` and `y` are the same.

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew  ok, I have updated the post. You can download the sample data from the google drive link.

Comment: @user2246849 I no label the column of the dataset. I have updated the post. You can download the sample data from the google drive link.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use "ravel" while converting the dataset to numpy array. [ravel](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) is converting your 2-D array to 1-D and causing this error. You need not reshape it later if you avoid using ravel.

Use [to_numpy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) to convert your dataframe to numpy array. That should solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, I type it like this
# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('14ns.csv')
X = np.array(dataset.to_numpy())
y = np.array(dataset.to_numpy())

Then, I get this error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hong1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 24, in <module>
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (767, 1776) instead.

Comment: Why are you assigning `np.array(dataset.to_numpy())` to both `X` and `y`?? `y` should contain only the target variable, not the whole set of features.

Comment: Oh, so what should I do for the y?

Comment: `y` stores the target variable. You could look up some crash courses / tutorials on machine learning on Google, or some of the examples in scikit-learn docs, if you are not familiar with these concepts.

Comment: @KohKhengHong, Aravind is actually correct. Removing the `.ravel()` will solve the problem for your X. On the other hand, your `y` variable is your target variable and it should be a vector of the same length as your number of features.

Comment: @AravindG. okay, I will try to get more knowledge regarding the ML. Once again, thank you so much for your help.